# Google Identity Service Sign In with Google buttons supporting different callback functions for each button

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I am trying to support multiple [Sign In with Google buttons](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) on the same webpage that all need to be configured with unique [callback functions](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#callback).

It seems as though a callback function can only be provided via the `callback` field in the [configuration object](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#IdConfiguration) passed to [google.accounts.id.initialize](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.initialize). In [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#callback) there is this warning “The google.accounts.id.initialize method should be called only once, even if you use both One Tap and button in the same web page”. In addition, there are two other notes about the initialize method:

- "You only need to call the google.accounts.id.initialize method once even if you use multiple modules (like One Tap, Personalized button, revocation, etc.) in the same web page."
- "If you do call the google.accounts.id.initialize method multiple times, **only the configurations in the last call will be remembered and used**."

Each time I render a new Sign In with Google button I have to call initialize again in order to have the correct call back configured for the current Google button I am displaying. This causes all buttons on the page to be configured with the same callback.

Is there a way to provide a unique callback function to each Google Button on the same page or do they all need to share the same configurations?

Answer (score 0):

GIS does not support different initialisations (and thus different callbacks) for different sign-in flows. Instead, the credential response you receive from GIS includes a 'select_by' property which tells you how the user has elected to sign-in. This can be 'btn' or 'user' (which I assume one-tap). So with the response telling you how the user has signed-in, you can easily modify your callback function conditionally.